# 2-layer children - I can't wrap my head around this! ;-)

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

So I have three channels. One is called **Event Categories**, one is called **Events**, and one is called **Standard Pages**.

For other reasons I don't want to get into here, I have decided not to use the native EE "Category" functionality to accomplish this.

What I need to have happen is this. **Events** are related to **Event Categories** and then **Event Categories** are related to **Standard Pages**. So if I associate an **Event Category** with a **Standard Pages** entry, it needs to list all of the specific **Events** associated with the **Event Categories** associated with that **Standard Page** entry. These **Events** should be listed under a title h3 element for each **Event Category** listed. If an **Event Category** is related to the **Standard Page**, but has no active **Events** associated with it, it should not be shown.

I am sure this is a very easy thing to accomplish, but relationships always mess with my head and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out the template code to accomplish this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It’s not crystal clear which channels those Playa fields are on. For example, “Events are related to Event Categories” just tells me there’s either a Playa field on Events pointing to Event Categories *or* there’s a Playa field on Event Categories pointing to Events. Can you please update your post making it clear where the actual Playa fields are? My hunch is that Jason got it backwards.

Comment: There is a Playa field on the Events channel where you can pick an entry from the Event Categories channel. There is also a Playa field on the Standard Pages channel to select an entry from the Events Categories channel. Hope that helps! Man, relationships mess with your head! ;-)

Comment: So: Standard Pages have Events, and Events have Event Caterogies. And for a given Standard Page, you want to list all of its Events, organized by Event Category. Got it.

Comment: Does that mean I was right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By golly, I've got it!**

Thanks to everyone for your help! Like I said, relationships are crazy-hard to wrap your head around and I couldn't have figured it out without your help. The answer turned out to be **Co-Parents**.

Here is the final answer to my question...

```
{standard_page_events var_prefix="cat"}
    <h4>{cat:title}</h4>
    {exp:playa:coparents var_prefix="event" channel="events" child_id="{cat:entry_id}"}
        {event:title}<br>
    {/exp:playa:coparents}
{/standard_page_events}
```

This article really pushed me in the right direction.

http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/playa-coparents

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both the **Standard Pages** and **Events** channels have a Playa field with entries from the **Event Categories** channel, the following should work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
  {exp:playa:children var_prefix="cat"}
    {cat:exp:playa:parents field="event_category" var_prefix="event"}
      {if '{event:count}' == 1}
        <h3>{cat:title}</h3>
        <ul>
      {/if}
          <li>{event:title}</li>
      {if '{event:count}' == '{event:total_results}'}
        </ul>
      {/if}
    {/cat:exp:playa:parents}
  {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It's confusing for me too, but the [Playa terminology page](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/terminology.html) helps me understand what's what.

Standard Page = Parent *(The entry that has the Playa field.)*
Event Category = Child *(The entry that you selected in the Playa field.)*

Event = Parent *(The entry that has the Playa field.)*
Event Category = Child *(The entry that you selected in the Playa field.)*

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the field names and it doesn't seem to do anything except cause the page to time out. I think you're on to something with the var_prefixes, but I don't know what's causing it to hang?

Comment: I was using 4.3.3. I doubt that the later versions would break it... but... maybe? I had almost that exact code, but on my index page. I had `dynamic="no"` added to my outer channel entries loop to display all the pages. Don't see why it would be any different though.

Comment: What version of EE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part here is organizing Events by Event Categories. I can think of two ways to do it:

- Loop through all possible Event Categories, and for each one, check to see if there are any events for the current category that were selected by the current page.
- Just loop through all the events, and use a little PHP on the template to index them by their Event Categories, and then output them in a separate loop.

Neither option is great, but I’m leaning toward the second one because it should be a bit more efficient.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="standard_pages" ... }

    {!-- Get all of the events grouped by their categories --}
    <?php
        $events_by_cat = array();
    ?>
    {exp:playa:children channel="events" var_prefix="event"}
        <?php
            $cat_ids = array({event:exp:playa:child_ids channel="event_categories" delimiter=", "});
            $event = <<<EOD
                <h4>{event:title}</h4>
                <p>{event:event_description}</p>
                ...
EOD;
            foreach ($cat_ids as $cat_id)
            {
                $events_by_cat[$cat_id][] = $event;
            }
        ?>
    {/exp:playa:children}

    {!-- Loop through all categories, fetch their titles and list their events --}
    <?php foreach ($events_by_cat as $cat_id => $events): ?>

        <?php $cat = get_instance()->db->select('title')->where('entry_id', $cat_id)->get('channel_titles')->result(); ?>
        <h3><?php echo $cat[0]->title ?></h3>

        <?php foreach ($events as $event): ?>
            <?php echo $event ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Ewwww. I just got back to check this out and I am kind of floored that I would have to use PHP to accomplish this? Is this really a case that Playa cannot handle natively? Seems like a simple thing in theory, doesn't it? It's just two levels of relation. Any thoughts Brandon? I am really hesitant to implement a solution that involves PHP.

Comment: Playa does not natively allow for this to happen easily. There are a couple ways to do it without enabling PHP in your templates (NEVER DO THAT); i'm trying to do something else right now but will write up an answer shortly.

Comment: I appreciate your help. In my head it doesn't seem like it should be this hard? Also, Adrienne, I am open to completely changing how this is set up if I need to.

Comment: As I said, the only other thing I could think of would be to loop through *all* categories, and for each one check to see if there are any events for the current category and page. That route would require an {embed} and a ton more {exp:channel:entries} calls (one per category), and won’t be pretty either. At least my proposed solution is efficient. And regarding PHP in templates – never say never.

Comment: So why would you need to loop through ALL categories? Here is the logic I was following. Load a **Page** entry, see what **Event Categories** are related to that **Page**, then look up those **Event Categories** and pull in all **Events** related to the **Event Categories** assigned to that **Page**. That's the logic you were following as well, right? Seems simple in theory! :-)

Also, I figured I would cache the rendered page for 24 hours so that would help on queries, etc.

Comment: Ohh and it's worth mentioning. Even though they are going to have a hundred categories or so, they will usually only assign 1-3 categories to any given page. Not sure if that helps the discussion, but I thought I would throw it out there!

Comment: Because you said yesterday, there is no Playa field directly relating categories to pages. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/2-layer-children-i-cant-wrap-my-head-around-this/9850?noredirect=1#comment11515_9822

Comment: There are 3 channels. Events > Event Categories > Pages. There is a Playa field on the Events Channel that you relate an Event Categories entry to. There is also a Playa field on the Pages Channel that you relate an Event Categories entry to. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: So is the problem here that I SHOULD have had a Playa field on the Event Categories channel relating events to that category instead of what I did by relating a category to an event? Is that what's making this so difficult?